How to delete GP stroke in 3d viewport?
This has been bugging me for a while. How do I get rid of the little floating GP stroke in the 3d workspace but still keep the brushstrokes on my object? It's really annoying and I can't find a way to get rid of it without also getting rid of the strokes I want to keep.
Deleting the unwanted stroke in Object mode also deletes the strokes I want to keep.
I haven't been able to find any solution other than making the parent GP stroke really small and moving it out of view of the camera. Thanks in advance.

Switch to Edit mode while you have your Grease Pencil object selected. You can press Tab on your keyboard to do so as well.

Using the Select tool, you can select which elements (i.e. vertices, lines, etc.) to delete. Personally, I just use Linked Select by hovering my mouse over the connected stroke and pressing L on the keyboard.

Press X to delete.
